# Communication between two Ev-3 bricks

Tags: ev3, compatibility

How the communication between two Ev-3 bricks is done over Bluetooth? What is the nature of data that can be communicated?

Comment: Note that if you don't need wireless, the USB daisy-chain connection is a very convenient way to make several (up to 4 if I'm not mistaken) bricks work together - as you only need to create one program in which you can simply address all ports of all bricks.

Comment: It shouldn't be too much different from the NXT's Bluetooth capabilities, from what I perceive.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using EV3 Bluetooth blocks.
You can send integers, string or boolean using different "mailboxes" so the receiver just need to use the Block to read from a particular mailbox to get the data.

Maybe I write a post where I detail all this more because LEGO documentation isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the EV3 bluetooth blocks in the blue tab of the programming software.

One thing though:
The two bricks have to have different names. Like "Kim" and "John".

Check the EV3 help too.